# Custom Attribute for asp.net Checkbox: How to retrieve it?

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, repeater, custom-attributes

I am using a repeater with the Item Template of a checkbox.  Here's my checkbox template:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkBox" Text='<%# Eval("Text") %>' Value='<%# Eval("Value") %>' />
```

Now, I know asp checkboxes do not have a value attribute, but I read somewhere that you can put that in there and it will work the same.  I'll have to look it up again to see if I read it wrong.  However, just in case it is possible to put the custom attribute in there, how do I retrieve it in code behind?  I looked at the source after the page is created and there is no attribute in the control that says "value".  Any ideas?  Thanks.

EDIT:

Here's where I saw you can add the custom attribute:

http://www.daveparslow.com/2007/08/assigning-value-to-aspnet-checkbox.html

Comment: Side note, placing that additional tag will cause a validation error.  You may want to annotate it with a `data-` prefix and set your DOCType to XHTML 5 to prevent this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve values from your server controls through the attributes collection.  In your case,

```
string s = chkBox.Attributes["Value"];
```

However, as a suggestion and as my comment states, if you want a valid page, you should change your doc type to HTML 5 and use the `data-` annotation on your custom attribute.

Comment: For whatever reason, there wasn't anything that straight forward online.  When I tried looking up custom values for asp.net checkbox, it kept referring me to InputAttributes and it did nothing for me.  But I just verified that it worked, thanks.